# Why bother with Apples Reachability class and not just try making the actual connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

Apple provides a class called Reachability. I almost used it but then found a lot of people reporting problems on SO. For example it would report false positives or bring up the same error notification multiple times making the user tap a "no internet" alert view away multiple times.

Why can't I simply try to fetch data in the background and see what I get?

```
NSData *download = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

I checked: When there is no internet, `download` is just going to be nil. Then I can bring up a UIAlertView and complain.

Also some users say it is stupid to just check for "internet connection" because Reachability only tells if connected to Gateway. Gateway can have no internet. My WiFi router does this all the time. iPad has WiFi reception but no internet.

Others say it's better to test for a particular URL and see if server is there.

So why bother with the Reachability class then? Why not try the actual download and if nothing happens suppose something is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How do I determine whether the currently active network connection is Wi-Fi or the carrier's network?**

The `SCNetworkReachability` API allows an application to determine the status of a system's current network configuration and the reachability of a target host. One of the flags returned by the API, `kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN`, will tell you if a network connection to the target host uses the carrier network...

From Networking & Internet Coding How-To's

Answer (score 1):

One reason is you would check reachability on load and if there is no internet don't even show buttons to reach out to the internet. This would save you from having to load the entire download before you know if its available.

In many instances you're right. But sometimes you just want to check long before you would actually download anything.

Also if you look around on Github there are a lot of Reachability Classes that do a better job than the one Apple has included.