# Swift - Testing a connection to a website and available ports

Tags: swift, networking, reachability, cfnetwork

I haven't been able to find a solid answer to this question anywhere on the internet, and I feel like there has to be a simple answer. I'm trying to test wether I have a connection to specific ip addresses and certain ports with Swift on Mac OS.

I really just want to return true/false if I'm able to connect to a URL, or specific ports associated with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is very similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10801527). There are plenty of good answers. Also make sure to check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8812459) as well.
I would recommend the following article:
[https://marcosantadev.com/network-reachability-swift/](https://marcosantadev.com/network-reachability-swift/)
It is rather solid.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `Network` framework. It is super powerful and flexible and allows direct access to protocols like TLS, TCP, and UDP for your custom application protocols. It is Swift-ready and easy to use.

```
import Network

let connection = NWConnection(host: "www.google.com", port: .https, using: .tcp)
connection.stateUpdateHandler = { (newState) in
    switch(newState) {
    case .ready:
    print("Handle connection established")
    case .waiting(let error):
    print("Waiting for network", error.localizedDescription)
    case .failed(let error):
    print("Fatal connection error", error.localizedDescription)
    default:
    break
    }
}
connection.start(queue: .main) // Use some other queue if doing it for real.
```

The code above will work even in Playground (and fire the `stateUpdateHandler` at least once). In real app `stateUpdateHandler` will be called every time the state changes.
BTW, `URLSession`, is built upon this framework.